# Show that $\vdash P(y) \leftrightarrow \forall x(x=y \rightarrow P(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

List of axioms:

$(A1)$ - All Tautologies.

$(A2)$ - $(\forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta)) $.

$(A3)$ - $(\forall x \alpha) \rightarrow [\alpha]^{t}_{x} $ if x is free for t in $\alpha$.

$(A4)$ - $\alpha \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha) $ if x is not free in $\alpha $.

$(A5)$ - $ x = x$

$(A6)$ - $(x=y) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ if $\beta$ if obtained by substitution of at least one occurrence of x free for y in $\alpha$.

Modus Ponens as inference rule.

Generalization Theorem:

If $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ and x do not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$

And Deduction Theorem.

Again, the strategy is to prove:
 $\vdash P(y) \rightarrow \forall x(x=y \rightarrow P(x))$

and the converse.

I tried to use (A6) and got stuck with $(x=y) \rightarrow (P(y) \rightarrow P(x))$ after proving that $(x=y) \rightarrow (y=x)$

For the converse, I reach $(x=y) \rightarrow P(x)$ and need to prove $P(y)$. How do I suppose to prove $P(y)$ in this condition?

Is there an easier way to prove this theorem?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you had the Deduction Theorem already.

Comment: Sorry, i have it, just forgot to mention it.

Comment: Assume $P(y)$. Then by $x=y\to(P(y)\to P(x))$ and tautology you get $(x=y)\to P(x)$. Now generalize.

Comment: Which tautology should I assume? I can't see it.

Comment: For example, $A\to(B\to(A\to C))\to(B\to C)$, with $A$ being $P(y)$. Or alternatively $(B\to(A\to C))\to(A\to(B\to C))$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That does it! Thanks! For the converse, i assume by deduction theorem that $\forall x((x=y) \rightarrow P(x))$. Using (A3), I reach in $(x=y) \rightarrow P(x)$ with MP. Do I need to use some tautology again in order to prove $P(y)$?

Comment: Try to reach $y=y\to P(y)$ instead ...

Comment: I am trying to reach it, but I'm a little lost, since I'm new to first order logic. It seems that I have to reach it coming from $(x=y) \rightarrow P(x)$ but then I can't find an axiom that fits it.

Comment: A3; take $t=y$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you.